# Proof of Euler's formula for connected planar graphs with linear algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, graph-theory

Euler's formula states that if a finite, connected, planar graph is drawn in the plane without any edge intersections, and v is the number of vertices, e is the number of edges and f is the number of faces (regions bounded by edges, including the outer, infinitely large region), then

$$ v − e + f = 2 $$

-Wikipedia, Planar graph.

There are many proofs exist to the above result. One e-page that surmise many of them is well known, and could be found here - http://www.ics.uci.edu/~eppstein/junkyard/euler/all.html.

Yesterday I have been watching lecture 12 in linear algebra by Gilbert Strang, MIT. He introduced some application of the four fundamental subspaces, and one of them were Euler's formula, but I couldn't to follow his explanation this time.

Can someone sketch me a proof of Euler's result in linear algebra terms?

Thank you.

Comment: When in the video does he mention it?

Comment: He mention it in 39:20.

Comment: For those not wanting to watch: he derives Euler's formula by interpreting the kernel of the transpose of a graph's oriented incidence matrix as counting faces.

Answer (score 3):

Let $G$ be a connected and planar graph, where each edge is assigned an (arbitrary) orientation.  Let $m = E$ denote the number of edges, and let $n = V$ denote the number of columns.  The *incidence matrix* of $G$ is the $m \times n$ matrix $A$ for which
$$
A_{ij} = 
\begin{cases}
-1 & \text{edge $i$ leaves node $j$}\\
1 & \text{edge $i$ enters node $j$}\\
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
***Note:*** *The incidence matrix is usually defined to be the transpose of this matrix (as it is defined [here for example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incidence_matrix)), but we'll stick to Strang's convention.*

With that, Strang tries to convince us of the following:

> **Claim:** $\operatorname{rank}(A) = n-1$
>
> **Claim:** $\dim N (A^T)$ is the number of (internal) "faces" of the graph $G$.  In the usual notation, $\dim N (A^T) = F-1$.

To prove the first claim, we see that the pivot columns upon row-reducing $A^T$ produce a spanning tree of $G$. Alternatively, it suffices to note that since $G$ is connected, $N(A)$ must be the space spanned by $(1,\dots,1)$.

The second result is not strictly "proven", but it is convincingly argued with Strang's example.

With that, the dimension formula yields
$$
N(A^T) = m - r(A^T) \implies\\
F - 1 = m - (n - 1) \implies\\
F - 1 = E - (V - 1) \implies\\
V - E + F = 2
$$